# Magento 2 search page product name,image, price not displaying

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 search page product name not displaying[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the attribute is set to "Yes" in "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" product attribute option.

Comment: I did but still I cant see the product name, picture and price.

Comment: Do reindex and check

Comment: not working Iamrajavarien